# How to copy an image file in android studio by code

Tags: android, image, file, copy

How can i copy an image file from folder 'A' to folder 'B'. I tryed this:

```
cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

How do i get the url selected image and the make a copy to an specific folder...?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Implement `onActivityResult()` to get the result from `ACTION_PICK`. Get the `Uri` out of the result `Intent` using `getData()`. Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in that `Uri`. From there, it is standard Java I/O, copying from the `InputStream` to some `FileOutputStream` that you create.

Comment: Thanks, I undertand but how do i set the uri file to FileOutPutStream..?